# Is Boost guilty of being un-Boost-like?

Tags: c++, boost, parsing, boost-spirit

I was just reading the intro to the Boost::Spirit LL Parser framework. The preface suggests that the author and creator likes to use such parsing technology to read in program options. Doesn't Boost have its own library for program options?

I am wondering, does the Boost committee review all the library notes for common themes and style? It seems the doc for each library have their own flavor to them.

Small gripe for an otherwise amazing piece of software, I just found it curious.

Answer (score 10):

Simply, Spirit existed before the Boost.Program-Options library. Now, I always use Boost.Program-Options instead of hand-rolling my own using Spirit.

Answer (score 9):

You're right, not all boost libraries are particularly boost-like. Spirit is a very good example of this. Part of the reason is that when it was accepted, other boost libraries were not yet accepted/sufficiently mature for Spirit to use them. (That's why there are something like 3 Boost libraries that define their *own* (incompatible) placeholder values _1, _2 and so on).

In most of these cases, I believe they're gradually working on getting these oddities merged back together. But afaik, Spirit was added because it was such a big and impressive thing, that it's "unboostness" was forgiven. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Spirit in Boost may one day be Boost in spirit :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Joel said, we didn't have Program-Options when Spirit was born. Hartmut Kaiser and I (both Spirit developers) use Program-Options at work, instead of rolling out our own Spirit parser. Program-Options does a lot more than parsing, and, at least for our needs, the performance of our command line parsing isn't important. For performance critical parsing, I'd definitely use Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a Boost style committee. ISO's WG21 will spend a bit more time on common style, but even they managed to forget std::ifstream::ifstream((std::string const& filename)